# How to properly setup graceful-shutdown community

Tags: cisco, bgp, cisco-ios-xr

I'm trying to setup graceful-shutdown community but it looks I cannot make it working.

```
community-set comm-graceful-shutdown
  65535:0
end-set
!
route-policy SOMEIX-IN
  ! tried set local-preference 0 here to test, useless because it is rewritten
  set community (65535:0) additive
  if community matches-any comm-graceful-shutdown then
    set local-preference 0
  else
    set local-preference 95
  endif
  ! if I put set local-preference 0 here, I can achieve to have localpref 0
end-policy
```

In the end I got:

```
  Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 95, valid, external, best, group-best
  Received Path ID 0, Local Path ID 0, version 416851127
  Community: <some communities, then:> graceful-shutdown
```

Has someone an Idea on what point(s) I'm wrong please ?

Comment: Is the route-policy correctly applied to the peer?

Comment: Yes it is, because the localpref 95 is applied, or the 0 one if I put it in the end.

Comment: I suspect (but can't test) that you can't set a community on a received route, then test for it.

Comment: Communities cannot be set on inbound routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the community string needs to be set by the sender, not the route policy. The route policy sets the community at the end of the processing, so the if test never sees the community string and sets local pref to 95. The result is local pref 95 and community 65535:0 being added.